# How does Python compare strings of different length?

Tags: python, string, boolean, compare

For example suppose I run "12"<"7" , the answer is TRUE. Why?

Comment: this might help. [String Comparison in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-comparison-in-python)

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Because character-wise `7 > 1`

Comment: ok so $7>1$, but what about "2"? What is the second character in 1st string compared with in the second string? @mozway

Comment: @Alex then it's compared against nothing (or the empty string) and the longest string is greater (if all previous values were equal). Example: `'1' > ''` -> `True`

Comment: Because strings are compared _alphabetically_, just as the word "Aardvark" comes before "Be" in a dictionary.